# Find index of substring in Julia

Tags: julia

How to find index of substring `bc` in the string `abcde`?

Something like `indexof("bc", "abcde")`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`findfirst`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/index.html#Base.findfirst-Tuple%7BAbstractString,AbstractString%7D) or [`findlast`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/index.html#Base.findlast-Tuple%7BAbstractString,AbstractString%7D) to find the position of the first or the last occurrence of a substring in a string, respectively.

```
julia> findfirst("bc", "abcde")
2:3

julia> findlast("bc", "abcdebcab")
6:7
```

`findfirst` and `findlast` will return a range object covering the beginning and the ending of the occurrence if the substring occurs in the string, or `nothing` otherwise. For the first index of the range, you can use `result[1]` or `first(result)`.

```
result = findfirst(patternstring, someotherstring)

if isnothing(result)
    # handle the case where there is no occurrence
else
    index = result[1]
    ...
end
```

There are also [`findnext`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/index.html#Base.findnext-Tuple%7BAbstractString,AbstractString,Integer%7D) and [`findprev`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/index.html#Base.findprev-Tuple%7BAbstractString,AbstractString,Integer%7D) functions. `findnext` finds the first occurrence of the substring after a given position, whereas `findprev` finds the last occurrence before a given position.

---

Note that `findfirst`, `findlast`, `findnext` or `findprev` are used not just to search in a string but also to search in other collections like arrays.

Comment: And `findall` . (Edit: Oh, actually `findall` does not work for string search.)

Comment: `findall` works for strings on git master, to be released in Julia 1.3.